# Get name of screen in stack navigator in bottom tab navigator - react navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following navigation setup:

```
BottomTabNavigator
    HomeTabStackNavigator
        HomeScreen
        FriendScreen
    AccountTabStackNavigator
        AccountScreen
        SettingsScreen
        HelpScreen
```

In `BottomTabNavigator` I need to get the name of the most downstream screen, so `HomeScreen` or `FriendScreen` or any other in the second level of indentation above. I tried doing:

```
const route = useRoute();
const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);
```

But this only returns the first level of indentation, `HomeTabStackNavigator` or `AccountTabStackNavigator`. How can I get the most granular screen name?